# Jquery Using Large No of Change Event Handlers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have set of `Jquery-UI-Tabs` which contains a save button for each tab. I want to track if any modification is done in the input fields in these tabs so that I can prompt the user to save the data before closing the application.

My idea is to use Jquery `change` handler to track modifications. I want to know if this is the best way to do this and if there are any performance disadvantages of using large no. of `change` event handlers. (I have to use about 40-50 change event handlers).

Comment: Why don't you try this plugin http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/form-track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this approach should work (depending on the specifics of your implementation)

Regarding performance , do you actually need 40-50 different change handlers? If the logic is the same, you can use event delegation to improve performance. For instance, if all the tabs are in an element with `class="tab-container"` you could use something like:

```
$(".tab-container").on("change", ":input", function(event){
  //some logic here
});
```

Comment: @NipunaSilva `on` is new to jQuery 1.7. If you can't upgrade, use `delegate` instead.